# Enforcing Canonical Host Name - Azure, IIS

Tags: azure, hosting, url-rewrite-module

I wish all requests to [www.liamblizard.co.uk](http://www.liamblizard.co.uk) to be redirected to [liamblizard.co.uk](http://liamblizard.co.uk)

This is the rule i've got in web.config to do the rewrite

```
<rule name="Canonical Hostname" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:2}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

but all requests to [www.liamblizard.co.uk](http://www.liamblizard.co.uk) fail

[image]

Do I need to do anything at the DNS level, ie: CNAME records, or should that IIS rule take care of everything?

The site is an Azure Standard Website if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your DNS, update the www CNAME record to point to liamblizard.co.uk